# Getting musicmetadata to work in the browser

Tags: javascript, filereader

Here is the library I'm trying to use:

https://github.com/leetreveil/musicmetadata

There are docs that showhow to use it, but their docs uses this function called `fs.createReadStream` to open the file. This functionality is for users of Node, and I believe is not avilable (or not applicable) in a browser enviornment. I assume I need to use `FileReader`? The file in my case is going to come from an `<input>` field.

Here is an example from the library's docs:

```
var parser = mm(fs.createReadStream('sample.mp3'), function (err, metadata) {
if (err) throw err;
  console.log(metadata);
});
```

I tried using this but it didn't work:

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var blob = reader.result;
        var parser = new musicmetadata(blob);

        parser.on('metadata', function (result) {
            console.log("MP3 tags!!!", result);
        });
    }         
    reader.readAsBinaryString($(this)[0].files[0]);
});
```

edit: I just discovered the browser example: https://github.com/leetreveil/musicmetadata/blob/master/example/index.html

My code is now this:

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function(event) {
    var parser = musicmetadata($(this)[0].files[0]);
    parser.on('metadata', function(result) {
        console.log("MP3 tags!!!");
    });
});
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
```

Comment: Did you look at the [browser example](https://github.com/leetreveil/musicmetadata/blob/master/example/index.html)?

Comment: It seems that `musicmetadata` does not expect a `Blob`, but a `File`. I'd try passing `$(this)[0].files[0]` directly to the `musicmetadata` method.

Comment: @Frxstrem I already tried that, it doesn' work either

Comment: Also, it seems like you should use just `musicmetadata(...)`, not `new musicmetadata(...)`.